# Can not assign function parameters to local array variable in `Zsh`

Tags: arrays, linux, shell, unix, zsh

I just try to assign parameters of function as local array variable, I tried

```
$test_print(){local foo=( "${@:1}" ); echo $foo[*]}; test_print a b c
```

I got

```
test_print: bad pattern: foo=( a
```

But if I remove `local` keyword

```
$test_print(){foo=( "${@:1}" ); echo $foo[*]}; test_print a b c
```

It's work

```
a b c
```

What is a problem here? How can I keep my array to local variable?

**Additional information**

I tried this on `bash` shell, it's work well either as `local` or `global` variable.

Comment: Note that `"$@"` and `"${@:1}"` are identical, to maintain the correspondence between `$@` and the positional parameters `$1`, `$2`, etc. `${@:0}`, by the way, would include `$0` at the beginning of the expansion. This makes `$@` different from arrays; `a=(1 2 3); echo ${a[@]:1}` produces 2 3, not 1 2 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make the wanted assignment, you have to separate the declaration of `foo` and the assignment of the value into two command:

```
test_print(){local foo; foo=( "${@:1}" ); echo $foo[*]}; test_print a b c
```

---

According to the [ZSH Manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands) `local` behaves like `typeset`:

> **local [ {+|-}AEFHUahlprtux ] [ -LRZi [ n ]] [ name[=value] ] ...
>
> Same as typeset, except that the options -g, and -f are not permitted. In this case the -x option does not force the use of -g, i.e. exported variables will be local to functions.

In the the paragraph on `typeset` it says:

> Note that arrays currently cannot be assigned in typeset expressions, only scalars and integers.